# Vibrate onclick

Tags: android, onclicklistener, vibration

Is there a way to get a button to vibrate but only when the if condition is verified?

Here's the code:

```
Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) ;

if(l2>=l1){
        insertactone.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    };
```

here is the onclick method for insertactone:

```
einsertactone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bsqlinsertactone);
    insertactone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.bsqlinsertactone:
                insertactoneClick();
                break;
            }
        }

        private void insertactoneClick() {
            startActivity(new Intent(
                    "com.example.everydaybudgetplanner.ACTONESQLENTRY"));
        }

    });
```

I want it to vibrate only if the the IF condition is verified.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

> is there a way to get a button to vibrate but only when the if condition is verified?

Yes. It looks like you have 95% of the code there already. Where did you get stuck?

You already have a `Vibrator` Object and a conditional. All you need to do now is call `vibrate()` like so:

```
Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

if(l2 >= l1) {
    insertactone.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    vibe.vibrate(100);
}
```

Don't forget that you need to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: it still doesn't work the way i want it to! i just want it to vibrate when the user clicks it if its already RED

Comment: What have you done to debug it? What does "it doesn't work" mean? Does it crash? Does it compile?

Comment: nothing like that! the problem is, it vibrates everytime i start the activity that contains thiss code. i want it just to vibrate when i press the button

Comment: i want it to vibrate just on click

Comment: Then move the `vibrate()` call (and the conditional) to `onClick()`.

Comment: for that i have to change l2 and l1 to final and i can't because they get their value from a select SUM

Comment: One option would be to change your Activity to implement OnClickListener (instead of creating an anonymous OnClickListener as you do now).

Comment: I used this solution and it worked well on most brand phones. But then I received some error reports on many Samsung's phone that got null from 

[(Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);.]
I wonder what's wrong there? This is the crash when doing vibe.vibrate(100);

[Attempt to read from field 'android.os.VibrationEffect com.android.server.VibratorService$Vibration.mEffect' on a null object reference]

Answer (score 3):

**For Kotlin:**

First of all, you have to add this to your Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

**Code:**

```
private var vibration = activity?.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
    vibration.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(200, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE))
} else {
    vibrator.vibrate(200)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />` 

 
Be sure you added permission at AndroidManifest

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12278247)

Comment: @Vini.g.fer How does this not attempt to provide an answer? It might be completely wrong, [but that doesn't mean we should abuse the review queues to delete it.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/1849664)

Answer (score 1):

```
private fun vibrateOnce(context: Context) {
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
       val vibratorManager =  context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_MANAGER_SERVICE) as VibratorManager
       val vib  = vibratorManager.defaultVibrator;
       vib.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(100,1 ))
   } else {
       val vib  = context.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
       vib.vibrate(500)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled vibration in your mobile phone.
Because i turned it off. And finally realised the error is not in code. In my default settings. This code works fine.`

Manifest permission for vibration generation:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Add this function in `onCreate` on in the function your button is defined:

final Vibrator
`vibe = (Vibrator) yourActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);`

Replace `yourActivity.this` with your own activity or if you declared a context you can write `context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);`

We can call it from anywhere:

```
`vibe.vibrate(80);`
```

80 represents the milliseconds (the duration of the vibration)

`